# Whats the status on the elsa workflows blazor integration?

Tags: elsa-workflows

Whats the status on the blazor integration ? I cloned https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-dashboard-blazor but when building I geterror "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error MSB3030 Could not copy the file "wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" because it was not found. Elsa.Dashboard.Client \packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.build\3.2.1\targets\ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets 230 ".

The link in the github to the "old" project returns a 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blazor integration sample was pretty outdated when you wrote this question, but I have recently [pushed an update](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/commit/287a1bb4bba8b99cb0578dd65d9a00631ae9ac0d) that includes two new Blazor sample implementations that demonstrate how to include the Elsa Dashboard component within a [Blazor WASM](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/tree/master/src/samples/dashboard/blazor/ElsaDashboard.Samples.BlazorWasm) and [Blazor Server](https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core/tree/master/src/samples/dashboard/blazor/ElsaDashboard.Samples.BlazorServer) project.